# Причины использования DownCast

Tags: c#, ооп

Для чего применяется *DownCast* в C#? С *UpCast* всё понятно, но вот с этим вообще ничего не понятно. Зачем его делать?

Comment: upcast на самом деле практически нигде не нужен

Comment: Уважаемые закрыватели, что в _этом_ вопросе-то плохого?

Comment: @VladD, (не "закрыватель", но.. ) Вопрос составлен как всеобъемлющий. Здесь нет практической проблемы. Где код, с ошибкой в котором автор не может разобраться? Где описание какой-то ошибки в работе инструмента/алгоритма? Нету? Это оффтоп - вопрос не в формате Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov: Да, здесь нет практической проблемы. Но по-вашему, вопросы наподобие «как работает X» нужно закрывать с комментарием «практической пользы от этого нет, делайте как написано в документации»? Или допустим вопрос «как правильно использовать async/await» — тоже не содержит практической проблемы.

Comment: @VladD, Да, я считаю что такие вопросы необходимо закрывать до их улучшения. Автор может найти и описать свою практическую проблему - ему достаточно пару-тройку раз поспрашивать у себя "почему я задаю этот вопрос?". Люди всегда задают вопросы с целью решения практических проблем, однако порой забывают их озвучить. Особенно часто такое бывает при общении с начальством и заказчиками.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov: Мне кажется это глубоко неправильным. Вопросы наподобие «для чего нужны классы», на мой взгляд, _очень_ важны, и намного более полезны будущему читателю, чем решение одного частного вопроса. Но мы, кажется, уходим в оффтопик, место нашему обсуждению — на Мете.

Comment: @VladD, может это и правильно, но правила есть правила. Это всеобъемлющий вопрос. Значит ему тут не место.

Comment: @metalurgus: Мне кажется, прятаться за правилами нехорошо. В конце-концов, мы сами и устанавливаем эти правила. Если вопрос хороший, то ему место на сайте, а если правила требуют закрыть хороший вопрос, то это плохие правила.

Answer (score 16):

В хорошо спроектированной системе необходимость в понижающем приведении (downcast'е) минимальна. Однако, существуют случаи, при которых он нужен. Вот несколько примеров. Обычная причина — слабость системы типов.

1. Представьте себе, что вы хотите запрограммировать класс с выделенным экземпляром. Но этот класс можно модифицировать, унаследовавшись от него. Это приводит к примерно такому коду:

   ```
   namespace System.Windows
   {
       class Application
       {
           static public Application Current { get; private set; }
           public Application()
           {
               Current = this;
           }
       }
   }

   namespace MyCoolApp
   {
       class App : Application
       {
           public MainVM MainVM { get; private set; }
       }

       class MyControl
       {
           // ...
           var mainVM = ((App)Application.Current).MainVM;
       }
   }
   ```

   Знакомый код, не правда ли?

   Такое приходится писать потому, что система типов не может выразить требование, чтобы `Current` было актуального типа, чтобы можно было написать `App.Current`.

   К аналогичной проблеме приводит попытка описать класс, который должен иметь оператор сравнения с другим экземпляром *того же* типа.
2. Другой валидный случай использования понижающего приведения — виртуализация по типу объекта вне иерархии классов.

   Представьте себе, что вам нужно сделать разное поведение кода для разных классов в одном дереве наследования. Обычно это решается при помощи виртуальных функций, но что, если функциональность не имеет отношения к самому объекту?

   Допустим, у вас есть иерархия типов геометрических фигур, и вы хотите добавить «сбоку» метод печати на консоль. Вносить этот метод абстрактным в базовый класс нет смысла, потому что вывод на консоль не имеет прямого отношения к геометрической фигуре. Поэтому приходится писать сторонний метод, выяснять runtime-тип объекта и приводить к нему.

   Ещё одно место, где приходится заниматься подобным — паттерн Visitor с крайне уродливой классической имплементацией (без `dynamic`).

   Это, наверное, тоже можно считать слабостью системы типов, по крайней мере в [будущих версиях языка](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/206) это должно решаться другими средствами.
3. Ещё один случай — существующий код, к «общему знаменателю» которого приходится приводить свой код. Например, много кода опирается на интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`, в котором значения свойств представляются наиболее широким типом — `object`. А значит, для работы с реальным значением нужен downcast. По сути, можно было бы отказаться от нетипизированного `INotifyPropertyChanged`, и пользоваться типизированным `IObservable<T>` для каждого свойства отдельно, но для начала придётся уговорить компанию Microsoft переписать WPF!
4. Ну и последний случай, который я вижу — необходимость «залатать» дыру, которую невозможно залатать правильными средствами из-за внешних условий. Например, нужно бы переделать иерархию классов, но дедлайн завтра. Или код производного класса поставляется другим отделом. Здесь может оказаться необходимым нарушить [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) и сделать что-то по-другому для конкретного порождённого класса.

Answer (score 5):

Ну вообще это много где может быть полезно. Для такого приведения даже существует специальный оператор:

```
Foo foo = (Foo)someObject;
```

Примером того, когда это может быть полезно является случай работы с необобщенными коллекциями:

```
List lst = new List() { new Foo() };
Foo foo = (Foo)lst[0];
```

Но вообще необходимо отметить, что подобное приведение на самом деле зачастую является не очень хорошей практикой, так как чревато ошибками в рантайме. В частности, если говорить о приведенном мной примере использование этого приема является необходимым злом, поскольку по тем или иным причинам в версиях .NET < 2.0 отсутствовали обобщенные коллекции, а потому по факту все подобные коллекции хранили ссылки на object со всеми вытекающими отсюда проблемами. В случае, если lst[0] имеет какой-то другой тип, будет сгенерировано исключение.

З.Ы. кстати, не путаете ли вы Downcast (приведение предка к наследнику) и Upcast (приведение наследника к предку)?

Comment: Для полноты напишите еще про безопасное приведение (as).

Answer (score 4):

Наиболее распространённая ситуация, когда мы точно знаем тип объекта, но по какой-то причине получаем его с типом object. Стандартные ситуации:

- В обработчики событий принято передавать `object sender`, но в большинстве случаев, подписываясь на событие, например, в winforms приложении, мы точно знаем, кто будет sender'ом. Например, если мы знаем, что это один из TextBox'ов в массиве, то приводим его к TextBox'у и делаем то, что нам нужно.
- Интерфейс `IClonable`. Метод `Clone` возвращает объект того же типа, что исходный (ну, если он этого не делает, то надо кому-то руки поотрывать), однако, объявлен от с типом `object`. Тут без приведения вообще никак.
- Устаревшие коллекции (которые не generic'и) всё делают через object, но использующий их, вероятно, складывает в них что-то конкретное, а не кашу из всего подряд.

Comment: Это практически и есть слабость системы типов.

Answer (score 3):

Причины, на самом деле, достаточно просты. Нам необходимо получить доступ к определенному поведению, которое реализуется только в классе-наследнике. Текущая архитектура не позволяет это сделать с помощью виртуальных методов. Получается, что других вариантов кроме как специализировать тип у нас не остается. Для более детального ответа необходим пример use-case, который вызвал данный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

К вышеизложенному можно добавить пример, с разными источниками данных. Когда, например, есть мобильное приложение и веб-сервис его поддерживаемый. В какой-то момент мы решили написать новый сервис, но не хотим отказываться от старого (у клиентов нашей компании стоят старые версии сервиса, а новый покупать не хотят). Тогда, чтобы реализовать дополнительные возможности в мобильном приложении, чтобы не переписывать мобильное приложение кардинально, приходится проталкивать через бутылочное горлышко интерфейса объекты, различающиеся как кот и кит.