# Зачем нужен upcast (повышающее приведение типа)?

Tags: c#, c#-faq

Недавно обсуждалось, [зачем нужен downcast](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432183/10105) — приведение типа от более общего к более конкретному. А нужен ли upcast (повышающее приведение) — явное приведение типов в обратную сторону, от более конкретного к более общему? Ведь мы ничего не теряем, работая с более конкретным объектом?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Для начала, общая причина, которая касается не только C#, но и большинства объектно-ориентированных языков: семантика. Если у программиста есть объект конкретного типа, он тем не менее может хотеть работать с ним как с более общим объектом: programming against an interface, not implementation!

   Это позволяет убедиться, что в коде не используются лишние, конкретные свойства, что будет мешать в будущем обобщить код.

   Разумеется, обычно это слишком строгая цель, и без этого можно обойтись.
2. Следующая причина — выбор перегрузки, неполиморфного метода. В зависимости от статического типа объекта (при совпадающем динамическом типе) могут быть вызваны различные перегрузки при одинаково выглядящем коде. Примеры:

   Вызов нужной перегрузки:

   ```
    void f(object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("обрабатываем объект");
    }

    void f(string s)
    {
        f((object)s); // избегаем рекурсии
        Console.WriteLine("дополнительная обработка для строки");
    }

    string s = "Пушкин";
    f(s); // вызывает перегрузку со строкой
    f((object)s); // вызывает перегрузку с объектом
   ```

   Ещё один пример, который часто встречается в коде:

   ```
    class X
    {
        public static bool operator == (X x1, X x2)
        {
            // оптимизация: проверим совпадение объектов
            if ((object)x1 == (object)x2)
                return true;
            // далее более дорогая проверка равенства по свойствам
        }
    }
   ```

   Вызов перекрытого метода:

   ```
    class Base
    {
        public void X() { Console.WriteLine("нужный метод"); }
    }

    class Derived : Base
    {
        public new void X() { Console.WriteLine("бесполезный метод"); }
    }

    Derived d = new Derived();
    ((Base)d).X();
   ```
3. Явная реализация интерфейса не позволяет вызвать метод по имени.

   ```
    class X : IDisposable
    {
        void IDisposable.Dispose() {}
    }

    var x = new X();
    // ...
    ((IDisposable)x).Dispose(); // по-другому не вызвать
   ```
4. В случаях, когда тип переменной выводится неявно из типа другой переменной, бывают случаи, когда нас не устраивает автоматически выведенный тип. Пример:

   ```
    var list = new[] { 1, 2 }.ToList();
    list.Add("ой");
   ```

   Мы хотим получить список `object`'ов, но выведение типов даёт нам список `int`'ов. Мы можем написать

   ```
    var list = new[] { (object)1, 2 }.ToList();
    list.Add("ой");
   ```

   так всё будет компилироваться.

   Ещё один тесно связанный случай — тернарный оператор. Если типы альтернатив различны, компилятор не может найти общий тип выражения, и приходится помогать:

   ```
    Animal animal = nya ? new Cat() : new Dog(); // не компилируется в C# <9
    Animal animal = nya ? (Animal)new Cat() : new Dog(); // компилируется
   ```

   (Очень похожая проблема возникает с `Nullable`-типами: `int? result = good ? 1 : null` требует явного преобразования одного из операндов-альтернатив.)

   Этот случай подсказал @Pavel Mayorov в комментариях, спасибо! Впрочем, как указывает @EvgeniyZ, в C# 9 с target typing в некоторых случаях преобразование типов не нужно:

   ```
    Animal animal = nya ? new Cat() : new Dog(); // компилируется в C#9
    var animal = nya ? new Cat() : new Dog(); // не компилируется в C#9
    var animal = nya ? (Animal)new Cat() : new Dog(); // компилируется
   ```
5. Ещё одно применение — неявная упаковка (boxing). Например, функции типа `GetEnumerator()` могут вернуть объект типа-значения, который реализует интерфейс `IEnumerator<T>`. Работать с ним не всегда удобно:

   ```
    static public IEnumerable<R> MultiZip<T, R>(
        this IEnumerable<List<T>> sequences,
        Func<IEnumerable<T>, R> resultSelector)
    {
        var enumerators =
                sequences.Select(s => (IEnumerator<T>)s.GetEnumerator()).ToList();
        try
        {
            while (enumerators.All(en => en.MoveNext()))
                yield return resultSelector(enumerators.Select(en => en.Current));
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (var en in enumerators)
                en.Dispose();
        }
    }
   ```

   Если бы мы забыли upcast к `IEnumerator<T>`, то в `enumerators` мог бы оказаться набор value type (и это так и есть в нашем случае!). При этом, поскольку мы мутируем наши энумераторы (`MoveNext`), то для случая value type мы бы вызывали этот метод на *копии* значения, и таким образом код бы не сработал.
6. Ещё один случай, наверное самый частый и самый незаметный — upcast происходит неявно и автоматически в том месте, когда мы присваиваем переменной базового типа выражение дочернего типа, или передаём в функцию, ожидающую базовый тип, аргумент производного типа. Например, такое бывает, когда мы пользуемся полиформными коллекциями (коллекция животных, содержащая и кошек, и собак).

Comment: Жду reinterpret_cast ;-)

Comment: @VladD можно обойтись неявным апкастом в 2.1 - `Object.ReferenceEquals(x1, x2)`

Comment: @PashaPash: Это да, просто пример валидного применения. Если такого метода нету (как например в примере на один выше), то без апкаста в той или иной форме (например, через дополнительную переменную) не обойтись. [Вы имели в виду 2.2, наверное.] // Хотя, как вы уже отметили, `object.ReferenceEquals` тоже делает (неявный) апкаст.

Comment: @VladD: Верно что нету, но как хотелось бы.

Comment: @VladD: Какое там UB? Там обычная генерация исключения: Type mismatch.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Кстати, на 6 вроде бы собираются сделать фикс в языке.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Спасибо, дописал.

Comment: Начиная с С#9, все примеры с тернарным оператором будут успешно отрабатывать даже, без преобразования.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Точно, этот кусок протух :) Сейчас допишу.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Дописал.