# var или Имя класса или псевдоним?

Tags: c#, language-lawyer, resharper

Добрый день.

Установил себе тут ReSharper. В настройках пока особо не копался, однако что заметил: на все объявления переменных (напрмер `Int32 SomeVar` или `MyClass MyClassEx` ) он предлагает переделать на `var...`
С другой стороны Дж Рихтер в CLR via C# советует всегда использовать имена класса, т.е. отказаться даже от использования псевдонимов.

Вот в связи с этим, возник вопрос: Есть ли какие-либо основания (кроме вкусовых предпочтений) использовать в определённых ситуациях определённые способы объявления переменных? ( возможны ли ситуации при которых разные способы объявления переменных по разному будут транслированы в IL?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Да, разница есть: если вы определяете тип переменной явно, он при этом может отличаться от типа выражения в правой части. Для невиртуальных методов это может привести к вызову разного кода.

Пример:

```
class A
{
    public void Greeting() { Console.WriteLine("Hallo, I am A"); }
}

class B : A
{
    public new void Greeting() { Console.WriteLine("Kekeke, I am B"); }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a1 = new B();  // заявленный тип переменной a1 - A
        a1.Greeting();   // выдаёт "Hallo, I am A"

        var a2 = new B();// заявленный тип переменной a2 - B
        a2.Greeting();   // выдаёт "Kekeke, I am B"
    }
}
```

Тот же эффект с открытыми полями (они всегда невиртуальны) и невиртуальными свойствами.

---

Существуют случаи, когда вам придётся указывать явный тип (или делать upcast) вручную. Пример:

```
class C : IDisposable
{
    void IDisposable.Dispose() { }
}
```

Такой код не компилируется:

```
var c = new C();
c.Dispose(); // нет такого метода
```

А такой компилируется:

```
IDisposable c = new C();
c.Dispose();
```

---

В случае, когда явно определённый тип совпадает с типом выражения, отличий нет.

---

Мне кажется, Рихтер слишком строг. В 2016 году точный тип давно уже не так важен. Семантика, смысл переменных намного важнее. Поэтому я для себя пользуюсь правилом:

- Там, где можно (то есть, практически везде), предпочитать алиасы типов (`int`, а не `System.Int32`).

  - Исключение: если это важно и я хочу подчеркнуть, что мой тип содержит именно 32 бита
- Там, где точный тип переменной реально важен или я хочу сделать на нём акцент, использовать его, иначе использовать `var`. Например, если какая-то операция возвращает мне `Stream` или там `NetworkStream`, мне обычно неважен конкретный тип, и я использую просто `var`.

Comment: [Ещё по теме](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433315/10105).

Comment: Уже всё расписали, добавить особо нечего. Но всё-таки я бы отметил одну важную вещь: если при замене `var` на конкретный тип или обратно код ломается, то стоит задуматься, хороший ли это код. Соответственно, выбор между `var` и конкретным типом — это холивар жанра расстановки фигурных скобочек, причём точно так же приверженцы разных языков имеют разные традиции.

Comment: @Discord: очень правильно, согласен.

Answer (score 8):

Есть ситуации, где использование `var` необходимо. Например, объявление анонимных типов, особенно при использовании LINQ. Пример:

```
var some = new { Id = 10, Name = "qwerty" };
```

Тип создаётся автоматически, и его название знает только компилятор, а потому без `var` тут не обойтись. IL-код будет генерироваться тот же самый как для типов, "прячущихся" под `var`, так и для явно объявленных. `var` - это лишь синтаксический сахар. 
А вообще следование или игнорирование данной рекомендации Resharper'а в общем и целом дело вкуса. Лично я предпочитаю `var` в очевидных ситуациях, там, где тип однозначно определяется из правой части. Например, при использовании конструкторов:

```
var some = new MyClass();
```

В данном случае использование `var`  оправдано во избежание дублирования имени класса (в качестве бонуса если вы захотите поменять тип переменной some на какой-то другой, править придётся на один раз меньше, хотя это мелочи).

Однако лучше не использовать `var`, если из правой части выражения нельзя однозначно определить, что это за тип. Например:

```
var some = GetData(); // тип переменной some не очевиден
```

в этом случае лучше явно указывать тип:

```
MyClass some = GetData();
```

Из моих личных предпочтений: я не указываю `var` при использовании примитивов. Вместо

```
var val = 0.0;
```

я предпочитаю писать

```
double val = 0.0;
```

Хотя это можно отнести к частным случаям правила об очевидности типа из правой части.