# О юзабельности var при разработке

Tags: c#, linq

Изучая Entity Framework натолкнулся на интересную вещь :

Для создания запроса мы можем использовать `var` :

`var phones = db.Phones.Where(p=> p.Company.Name=="Samsung");`

**либо** явно указывая  тип запроса ,например :

`Phone myphone = db.Phones.Where(p=> p.Company.Name=="Samsung");`

**что** меня натолкнуло на интересный вопрос :

*А можно ли при разработке использовать при создании переменных в большинстве случаев `var` вместо явного указания типа?Если нет, то почему нежелательно?*

А теперь наведу несколько примеров ,*в которых указаны различия между использованием `var` явным указанием типов*,почему мне кажется что все-таки `var` в большинстве случаев будет юзабельней и читабельней для разработчиков :

***1)*** Для объявления и дальнейшего использования таких структур как ***списки*** и ***словари***(к примеру) которые имеют в себе **уже** вложенные типы:

`Dictionary<Dictionary<String, String>, String> items = new Dictionary<Dictionary<String, String>, String>();`

*Соответственно* через `var` :

`var items = new Dictionary<Dictionary<String, String>, String>();`

(Ссылка на вопрос : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572693/why-use-var-instead-of-the-class-name)

***2)*** Использование `var` как итератор при перечислениях в коллекциях :

```
    class Item {
  public string Name; 
}
foreach ( Item x in col ) {
  Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
}
```

Код выше - скомпилируется без ошибок ,**но** при исполнении программы мы получим ошибку приведения типов . **Потому** что : сам цикл `foreach` может работать  с обоими интерфейсами `IEnumerable` и `IEnumrable<T>` . Здесь же результат исполнения имеет тип `object` и C# компилятор кастит(приводит) это  к типу `Item` . Следовательно , это небезопасно и может привести к ошибке работы программы ,**потому что** интерфейс `IEnumerable` может содержать объекты абсолютно любого типа.

Теперь вариант с **`var`** :

```
    foreach ( var x in col ) {
  Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
}
```

Здесь же тип `x` будет `object` если интерфейс `IEnumerable` и `T` если используется `IEnumerable<T>`

(Ссылка на вопрос : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425966/what-advantages-does-using-var-have-over-the-explicit-type-in-c)

***3)*** И само собой - использование `var` при запросах + либо получение объекта с **уже** определенным типом :

```
 var l = new List<string>(); // думаю ,очевидно какой тип будет у var
 var s = new SomeClass(); //
 var results = from r in dataContext.SomeTable select r; // Получение выборки из БД(путем LINQ To Enities)
```

Или запрос через подход *LINQ To Objects* :

```
var results = from item in someList
          where item != 3
          select item;
```

**UPD:** ну и пример с использованием анонимных типов :

```
var test = new {Id = 5,Name="Joseph"}

var result = context.MyTable.Select(x=>new {x.Id,x.Name}).ToArray();
```

(Ссылка на вопрос : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp?rq=1)

**Краткий вывод из примеров выше  :** `var` - достаточно неплохая вещь ,поскольку он строго типизирован + правильное название переменных позволяет ещё и повысить читабельность . Что в суме значительно повышает эффективность кода без ущерба для безопасности

**Вопрос в том** : есть ли преимущества использования явного указания типов при объявлении переменных перед `var`?

Я просто новатор в этом деле и хотелось бы услышать мнение опытных людей.Спасибо за конструктивный ответ!

Comment: Ещё можно добавить: использование var при выражениях с анонимными типами (когда тип результата придумает компилятор). Хотя сам вопрос, когда использовать var, а когда нет - дело холиварное, есть много доводов за и против. Потому ответ один- используйте то, что решает задачу и что предпочтительно в вашем проекте/команде/компании

Comment: ```Я просто новатор в этом деле``` :) новатор?

Comment: Опыта у меня не так много, но, var/auto полезны только тех местах где не хочется дублировать типы, однако, бывают случаи, на вроде: var data = DataFactory.getValue(); И вот попробуйте понять, какого у вас типа data смотря в код, не используя подсказки IDE :D Аналогично с плюсовым auto. Так что, в остальном, у этих операторов есть плюсы и удобства.

Comment: [Статья](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions) на сайте Microsoft. Там рекомендации, когда лучше использовать `var`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну, если говорить о литературе, то есть книга "Инфраструктура программных проектов" (на англ она бесплатная - Framework Design Guidelines) - там описано когда что использовать. Но это все не свод жестких правил, просто рекомендации

Comment: @test123 Как я говорил, есть много за и против, это нескончаемый холивар.

Comment: @tym32167 имел ввиду новенький)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ просто было у меня было предположение что это больше от компаний зависит ,возможно ,политика которых ограничивает использование `var` и тд

Comment: @tym32167 там есть пример где `var l = new List<string>();` - что равноценно `List<string> l = new List<string>();`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо большое за ссылку ,но в вопросе ,я уже пытался высветить похожие моменты

Comment: @clyde я писал про анонимные типы, а не про генерики. ```var zzz = new {Id = "asdasd", Name = "asdasd"};```

Comment: @tym32167 понял ,добавлю пожалуй в примеры)

Comment: @clyde У тебя же linq в тегах, вот и используй linq для примера с анонимными типами, например ```var result = context.MyTable.Select(x=>new {x.Id,x.Name}).ToArray();```

Comment: Найдите дубликат, кто-нибудь! Эта тема уже перетиралась на сайте, и кажется не один раз.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [var или Имя класса или псевдоним?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537169/var-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%98%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc)

Comment: @VladD на все дубликаты, что я нашел, ты и отвечал :)

Comment: @tym32167: Наверняка :) Но я с телефона, искать не так просто.

Comment: @tym32167 там дубликат о невкусовых предпочтениях. это вопрос - о вкусовых :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`var` - это ключевое слово для *компилятора*, а не для *человека*. Хорошее<sup>*</sup> использвование `var` - это когда вы хотите сказать компилятору:

> Компилятор, тут тип для человека или очевиден из контекста, или вообще неважен. Выведи сам!

Плохое<sup>*</sup> использование `var` - тип важен для читающего ваш код, неочевиден из контекста, но вы все равно написали `var`. Тем самым вы говорите разработчику, читающему ваш код через год:

> Вот ты пытаешься починить в моем коде хитрый баг, набрал себе в голову те 5-7 вещей которые можешь удержать. А теперь выбрось их и начни выяснять тип этой переменной!

---

Стандартное правило:

1. Можно писать `var`, если при *чтении кода человеком* тип переменной прямо виден из контекста:

   - тип переменной явно написан в той же строчке: `var a = new B()`
   - тип переменной неявно написан в той же строчке:

     ```
     var some = BFacrory.Create();
     var tasks = dataContext.Tasks;
     ```
   - тип прямо следует из кода

     ```
     foreach (var task in dataContext.Tasks) ...
     ```
   - и еще куча случаев, которые можно описать как "тип очевиден".
2. Можно писать `var`, если тип переменной не важен человеку, читающему код. Например, при использовании анонимных типов в цепочке LINQ-запросов. В этом случае важен не конкретный тип, а поля, которые в нем есть - а набор полей прямо виден из контекста.
3. Можно писать `var`, если ваш код не будет читать никто и никогда. Например, если это [временный набросок, который никогда-никогда не станет постоянным](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%BA,_%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82_%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B9).
4. Нельзя писать `var` во всех остальных случаях.

---

Существует альтернативный подход (с которым я в корне не соглаен), призывающий писать var вообще всегда и везде, кроме случаев, когда [компилятор не может вывести тип](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965576/why-cant-an-anonymous-method-be-assigned-to-var), либо [тип, выведенный компилятором не устраивает разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/537170/177221).

- за такой подход: он очень устойчив к рефакторингу с переименованием и разделением типов
- против: подобный рефакторинг происходит достаточно редко, отлично поддерживается даже чистой студией, а читабельность кода от принудительно неявного указания типа значительно<sup>*</sup> страдает.

---

<sup>*</sup> По мнению автора ответа. Почувствуйте себя человеком, который вынужден перестать читать код ради выяснения, что ж это за var^Wзвездочка.

Comment: Ответ дейвствительно очень исчерпывающий ,спасибо !

Comment: А я дочитал до конца игнорируя звёздочки и никаккого дискомфорта не испытал :)

Comment: @Qwertiy значит читал невнимательно!

Comment: Внимательно. Даже обнаружил, что словарь засунули в ключ :)

Answer (score 6):

Код должен хорошо читаться. Если `var` способствует этому - используй его. Если нет - не используй. Всё просто.

Если из-за обилия `var` ты не понимаешь в какой момент времени какой тип у тебя хранится в той или иной переменной - не используй `var`. В противном случае - почему бы и нет?

Пример с `Dictionary` плох тем, что наличие таких generic'ов в проекте - уже само по себе проблема.

Comment: Код должен не просто хорошо читаться, но быть расширяемым, тестируемым, поддерживаемым, работающим и тд и тп. С таким же успехом можно ответить "Юзай var чтобы сделать лучше, если лучше не получается, не юзай var"

Comment: @tym32167 Каким образом синтаксический сахар относится ко всему описанному тобой? Это же не `dynamic`. А твоя формулировка совершенно правильная. Если `var` мешает, значит ему здесь не место. Если не мешает - значит, в самый раз.

Comment: @LunarWhisper мне кажется просто при разработке , разраб должен отчетливо понимать какой тип будет получать даный `var` - ибо проблема определения его типа не должна вообще возникать ,если уж человек осознанно его использует

Comment: Я просто хочу сказать, что твой ответ очень общий, а аргументы спорные. В каких случаях тебе надо знать все типы всех переменных в коде, что ты читаешь? Если тебе надо понять, что делает функция - то это должно быть ясно из её сигнатуры. Если надо понять как она это делает - это должно быть немного строчек кода, так как функции должны быть короткие. Если надо понять требования к функции - смотри юнит тесты. То есть, по сути, реальных ситуаций, когда надо знать тип переменной во время чтения кода, должно быть мало. А во время написания ты и так должен знать все типы, что используешь

Comment: Я потому и говорю, что вопрос холиварный, конкретного ответа на него нет, есть только общий - делай хорошо, не делай плохо.

Comment: @LunarWhisper, >>Пример с Dictionary плох тем, что наличие таких generic'ов в проекте - уже само по себе проблема.<< А можете пояснить?

Comment: @LunarWhisper Да, ещё, использование var или конкретного типа может влиять на то, как программа себя поведет. То есть это такие не чисто сахар, это сахар с мозгами :)

Comment: @test123 код должен быть читаемый и понятный. Это ```Dictionary<Dictionary<String, String>, String>``` - нечитаемо и непонятно :)

Comment: >>код должен быть читаемый и понятный<< А как быть, если под капотом такая гирлянда есть, и жёсткая параметризация спасает от ошибок на стадии компиляции? Допустим, я вижу IMyObject<T> item = ...; А по факту, этот объект типизирован каким нибудь <T<K,V>,<I,N<Y>>> ? При этом программист об этих внутренностях даже не знает.

Comment: @tym32167, эм.. словарь в качестве ключа словаря? Кажется, тебя надо String переставить в другое место :) И вообще, что же непонятного, если даже при чтении комментария заметно косяк?)

Comment: @Qwertiy воу воу, я просто пояснил это ```Пример с Dictionary плох тем, что наличие таких generic'ов в проекте - уже само по себе проблема```. Хотя я как то работал с проектом у которого уровень вложенности словаря в словарь был около 6-7 (точно не помню), ох я тогда намучился догонять для чего это и как работает :)

Comment: @tym32167 ты как-то упустил вопрос поддержки кода. А `var` - это одно из надёжных средств достижения write-only кода. Когда я вижу, что чужой код работает неверно, ищу ошибку, и не вижу ни одного типа, я даже не могу предположить - в чём ошибка. Например:
`var a = GetX();
var b = GetY();
var c = a / b;
return GetZ(c);`
Я понятия не имею, происходит работа с целыми числами или дробными. Или там вообще произвольный тип у которого переопределен оператор деления. Хотя код то вот простой - 4 строчки.

Comment: дак я ж написал вроде, что есть и за и против, что это холивар вечный, а ты споришь дальше. Есть куча за и против. Нет конкретных рекомендаций когда что использовать. Есть только общие рекомендации. Конечно ты найдешь пример, когда var вреден. А я найду пример, когда тип выражения указать невозможно или не имеет смысла. Ну и что толку от этого?

Comment: tym32167 тогда мне непонятна твоя позиция. Я же ответил, хорошо - используй, плохо - не используй. Это как раз самый верный ответ в данном случае.

Comment: @test123 в случае таких страшных Generic'ов заводят специализированные коллекции и их элементы, которые скрывают подобную логику, а не выпячивают её в public API. Если внутри одного словаря лежит другой, наверняка при работе с таким страшилищем будет куча логики, которая создает вложенные Dictionary, добавляет элемент по двум ключам и т.д. - вся она уезжает в кастомную коллекцию.

Comment: Моя позиция проста как тапок - на поставленный вопрос конкретного ответа нет, есть только общие рекомендации. Это я не тебе писал, а автору вопроса. :)

Comment: @LunarWhisper, Понял. Действительно) Меня вчера заклинило, сам же написал что есть IMyObject<T>, и такое определение что с var-ом, что без него - всё равно читаемо. А то что находится внутри и то что не видимо - к вопросу о var не имеет отношения. В общем, я сглупил...

Answer (score 2):

Правило на самом деле очень простое: код должен легко читаться, пониматься и отлаживаться, как вами, так и вашими последователями. Всё, что служит этому — хорошо и правильно, всё, что препятствует этому — плохо и неправильно.

Когда у вас стоит выбор между явным именем типа или `var` (при условии, что нет разницы для программы), подумайте, интересен ли читателю в этой точке точный тип, или нет. Если без указания точного типа текст программы не проиграет в ясности, смело пишите `var`. Не стоит утомлять читателя ненужными подробностями: знание того, что объект имеет тип `List<Task<byte[]>>.Enumerator`, обычно не нужно. Но если с `var` читателю придётся угадывать нужный тип, и этот самый конкретный тип **важен**, укажите его.

В моей практике, чаще всего точный тип *неважен*: читателю в большинстве случаев всё равно, имеет ли `id` тип `string`, `int` или `Id`. Но в тех немногих местах, где с `id` производятся вычисления, точный тип может оказаться важен. Вот в этом-то случае и нужно его указывать явно.

Различение случаев, когда точный тип важен и когда неважен, зависит от вашего опыта (и, возможно, от отзывов коллег).

---

Да, а ещё есть случаи, когда язык за вас решает, использовать `var` или указывать тип. Например, для анонимных типов можно использовать только `var` (вне контекста обращённых методов, конечно).