# Различия в создании экземпляра класса

Tags: c#

Есть ли какая-нибудь особая разница между этими созданиями экземпляров?

```
Program Fact = new Program();
```

и

```
var haha = new Program();
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Нет никакой разницы, вот если бы вы написали `object Fact = new Program();`, то разница бы была, а в вашем коде разницы нет.

Comment: Ну а также стоит почитать на ответы [данного](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/717938/220553) вопроса.

Comment: В данном случае разницы нет. Но в левой части вы можете явно указать любой базовый тип или интерфейс, который реализует класс Program (полиморфизм) или поддерживает implicit приведение из типа Program. ```var``` же просто берёт тот тип, который возвращает выражение справа от знака =.