# C# var VS явного объявления типа переменных

Tags: c#

Начал учить C# и задался вопросом.
Что лучше использовать, "var" или явный тип данных, наподобие: "byte", "int", "float", "char"....
Есть ли в них различие, и что лучше использовать?

Comment: на любителя как удобно. Просто не всегда известно вам что там под var, компилятору то известно

Comment: Это холиварный вопрос. Есть адепты обоих подходов. Одни хотят видеть тип переменной, другие считают такую необходимость признаком некачественного кода. Однозначного ответа на этот вопрос нет в природе .

Comment: А есть разница в производительности программы?. Например используя var, программа будет работать хуже и тд...

Comment: @Eveee Внутри в любом случае скомпилируется под статическую типизацию, потому что язык такой. `var` удобен для перебежчиков с языков динамической типизации. Но лично мне нравится описывать явный класс, так меньше шансов запутаться и совершить ошибку.

Comment: Разница в производительности может быть, но обычно она минимальная. Надо понимать, что var использует результат выражения справа, то есть `var i = 10;` i - будет целым числом, а для `var i = 10.5` - i будет числом с плавающей точкой. Для явного ж задания типа, например `int i = ....` - не важно, что будет справа написано, оно все равно будет преобразовано в int.

Comment: @tym32167, разницы в производительности не должно быть, потому что после компиляции никакого var уже нет

Comment: @АндрейNOP если на выходе ожидается один и тот же код - да. Если же сравнивать, утрируя, `var i = 0;` и `Object i = 0;` - то разница в боксинге.

Comment: @АндрейNOP https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/537170/179763

Comment: @tym32167, ну согласен, var — берет тот тип, что стоит справа без каких-либо махинаций, а при явном указании типа компилятор добавляет операции повышающего или неявного преобразования, но, видимо, я из тех, кто считает это *признаком некачественного кода*. В любом случае: 1. за var всегда скрывается какой-то конкретный тип и можно навести мышку на него и увидеть что это за тип; 2. после компиляции никакого var уже нет. Надо эти вещи понимать и проблем не будет.

Comment: @АндрейNOP я только указал, что с var и без var разница в результате может быть в некоторых случаях. А то, что будут или не будут проблемы - давайте не будем холиварить, особенно учитывая, что я тоже использую var.