# Как называется такая форма записи?

Tags: c#

Есть два класса Human и Student. Пусть, Student наследуется от Human. При создании экземпляра мы можем записать нечто в такой форме:

```
Human andrew=new Students();
```

Как называется такая форма записи ?

Comment: повышающее приведение типа

Comment: Вопрос по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433314/10105

Comment: @VladD, может стоило закрыть как дубликат?

Comment: @Grundy: А чёрт его знает, вроде бы полным дубликатом не является.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная форма записи называется повышающее приведение типа

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, то это полиморфное наследование.

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism