# Почему нельзя вызвать метод Progress<T>.IProgress<T>.Report (T)?

Tags: c#

```
var p1 = new Progress<int>(a => progressbar1.Value = a};
p1.Report(1); // нельзя, ошибка компиляции
IProgress<int> p2 = new  Progress<int>{b => progressbar2.Value = b};
p2.Report(2); // можно
```

1. Почему нельзя вызвать метод из переменной типа класса, а из переменной типа интерфейса можно?
2. Для чего так сделано?

Comment: _явная реализация интерфейсов_, сделана чтобы разделить возможное дублирование наименований методов в разных интерфейсах.

Comment: здрасьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1315985/objecta-%d0%b8-objectb-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-api

Comment: здрасьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1315985/objecta-%d0%b8-objectb-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что для реализации интерфейса вовсе не обязательно определять все методы этого интерфейса как открытые методы класса. Можно просто указать метод, который будет реализовывать интерфейсный метод, не давая ему вовсе имени:

```
class Progress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
    void IProgress<T>.Report(T value) { ... }
    // ...
}
```

При этом метод можно вызвать только через [восходящее приведение типа (upcast)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433315/10105).

Такая техника называется *явной реализацией интерфейса*. [Обращаясь к документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5) или [подглядывая в исходники](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/progress.cs,98) можно убедиться, что так оно и есть в случае класса `Progress<T>`.

---

(*Дополнительная информация по теме.*)

Обычно явная реализация интерфейса используется для случая, когда нужно реализовать несколько конфликтующих интерфейсов одновременно. Типичный пример: если мы реализуем `IEnumerable<T>`, то мы при этом должны реализовать и необобщённый `IEnumerable`, и нам нужно *два* метода `GetEnumerator`: один, возвращающий `IEnumerator<T>`, и один, возвращающий `IEnumerator`. Без явной реализации интерфейса это было бы невозможно без трюков (например, вспомогательного промежуточного класса). С явной реализацией обычно пишут так:

```
class C<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { /* реализация */ }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

---

Для чего же так сделано в классе `Progress<T>`? Можно только гадать, гугл и исходники ответа на вопрос не дали. Нескольких интерфейсов `Progress<T>` не реализует, так что использование явной реализации не является строго необходимым.

Предположу, что это сделано, чтобы стимулировать передачу в фоновые методы объекта не конкретного типа `Progress<T>`, а интерфейсного типа `IProgress<T>` (что позволит легко подменять реализацию на другую).

Comment: Почему нельзя было сделать явную реализацию классов?

Comment: @Alex78191: А что такое _явная реализация классов_?

Comment: Множественное наследование

Comment: @Alex78191: Не вполне понимаю ваш комментарий. Множественное наследование в C# есть только у интерфейсов. И в случае `Progress<T>` я не вижу, как и куда его применить. У нас есть один класс и один интерфейс, как тут устроить множественное наследование?

Comment: Вот именно его нет и спрашиваю почему не сделали.

Comment: @Alex78191: А для чего? Какую проблему оно в принципе могло бы решить? И как его тут можно было бы устроить? Покажите, если вам не сложно, код, который вы имеете в виду, потому что на словах мне не понятна ваша идея.