# UpCast/DownCast C#

Tags: c#

В процессе изучения языка C# сталкиваюсь, как и все новички, с трудностями понимания. Изучаю язык на нескольких ресурсах, так как каждую тему собираю по понятным для меня кусочкам.

Очередной босс, которого я не могу пройти - это UpCast/DownCast, который приправлен обобщениями.
Сначала всё казалось элементарным, темы проходные: Привёл к нужному типу, скрыл какую-то функциональность, засунул нужный тип в метод и всё отлично. Определил класс/метод/делегат/интерфейс с обобщением, в нужном месте подставил системный тип и готово - вы восхитительны ! На большинстве ресурсов на этих примерах повествование заканчивается, но не на ITVDN. Когда начали подставлять пользовательские типы я поплыл.

Объясните, пожалуйста, на примерах из реального мира, детских аналогиях или подобными методами, зачем это всё ??? Зачем мы приводим к типу интерфеса. а где-то присваиваем объекту производного класса ссылку на базовый ??? Когда закрываем обобщение пользовательским типом - это вообще к-к-комбо для моего мозга. Я получил понимание как это делается, но не знаю для чего и в каких случаях ( буду очень благодарен простым аналогиям ) я должен реализовывать эти возможности языка ??? Я почитал темы на форуме, но так и не смог понять для себя глобальный смысл этого мероприятия.

```
 public abstract class Shape { }
public class Circle: Shape { }

public interface IContainer<T>
{
    T Figure { get; set; }
}

public class Container<T> : IContainer<T>
{
    public T Figure { get; set; }

    public Container(T figure)
    {
        this.Figure = figure;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        IContainer<Circle> container = new Container<Circle>(circle);
        Console.WriteLine(container.Figure.ToString());
    }
}
```

Вопросы:

**1.С какой целью в данном примере мы присваиваем ссылку типа IContainer объекту Container ?**

**2.Закрывая Т типом Circle, что мы ожидаем получить ?**

Я не могу понять какой смысл в " public Circle Figure {get;set;}". Как идёт моя логическая цепочка:"Объекту типа Container присваиваем ссылку типа IContainer( Зачем ?? IConteiner и Container оба содержат только T Figure ). При этом мы закрываем  типом Circle ( переходим в класс Container  и видим что это отражается на типе свойства Figure и конструкторе. Тут начинается основной затык: public Circle Figure {get;set;} - как свойство Figure может быть типа Circle и что мы можем ему присваивать ???
Вероятно, нет понимания из-за отсутствия наполнения классов какими-либо свойствами, методами чтобы стало ясно какая функциональность добавляется/скрывается при выполненных приведениях и закрытии обобщений тем или иным типом ( на примере указанного выше кода ).

Comment: Добавьте код текстом, а не картинкой (Ctrl+K для форматирования), и немного конкретизируйте вопрос. Если получится - оставьте один короткий вопрос - первый, на который вы хотели бы получить ответ

Comment: `Зачем ... присваиваем объекту производного класса ссылку на базовый ??` - уже есть ответ на данный вопрос. [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433314/212981).

Comment: здрасте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1315985/objecta-%d0%b8-objectb-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.С какой целью в данном примере мы присваиваем ссылку типа IContainer объекту Container ?

Например, для того чтобы работать с объектом только как с контейнером. Приведу пример:

Представьте, что ваш `Container<T>` - более сложный класс, который предоставляет дополнительный функционал:

- сохранение значение контейнера в файл;
- сравнение двух контейнеров между собой.

Тогда `Container<T>` будет примерно таким:

```
public class Container<T> : IContainer<T>, IStorable<T>, IComparable<T>
{
    public T Figure { get; set; }

    public Container(T figure)
    {
        this.Figure = figure;
    }

    public void Store(T item, string filePath)
    { 
        // Реализация IStorable<T>
    }

    public int CompareTo(T other)
    {
        // Реализация IComparable<T>
    }        
}
```

И чтобы можно было работать с объектом `Container<T>` как с объектом, который можно сохранять в файловой системе, мы сделаем следующее:

```
IStorable<Circle> shapeToSave = new Container<Circle>(circle);
shapeToSave.Store(...);
```

> 2.Закрывая Т типом Circle, что мы ожидаем получить ?
>
> Объекту типа Container присваиваем ссылку типа IContainer...

Наоборот. Переменной типа `IContainer<Circle>` мы присваиваем ссылку на объект `Container<T>`.

По поводу обобщения. Вот у нас есть свойство:

```
public T Figure { get; set; }
```

Компилятор, когда видит строчку

```
IContainer<Circle> container = new Container<Circle>(circle);
```

понимает, что нужно создать класс, подобный `Container<T>`, где вместо типа `T` будет наш `Circle`. Поэтому свойство "магическим образом" становится типа `Circle`. После этой строчки мы этому свойству можем присваивать только объекты типа `Circle`.

Если что-то дополнительно нужно пояснить,отпишите об этом ниже.

Comment: А если мы вместо T передадим int, что будет?

Comment: @Monomax поскольку в данном случае у типа `T` нет никаких ограничений, то все будет точно так же, как и для пользовательских типов. Все будет работать. Главное - правильно написать реализацию интерфейсов.