# Как именно работает Upcast в C#?

Tags: c#, ооп

Из определения:
Апкаст - приведение экземпляра производного класса к базовому

Фрагмент кода апкаста для примера. Класс `Human` производный от класса `Mammal`.

```
Human human = new Human();
Mammal mammal = (Mammal)human; //Upcast
```

1. Если апкаст - это приведение экземпляра производного класса к базовому, то в данном случае экземпляр `human` класса `Human` должен был быть приведен к классу `Mammal`. Но после этого фрагмента кода у экземпляра `human` сохраняются методы и переменные производного класса. В чем тогда выражается приведение к базовому классу?
2. Если апкаст - это создание нового экземпляра базового класса на основе экземпляра производного (в данном случае `mammal` из `human`), то в чем разница между указанным выше кодом с апкастом и данным кодом: `Human human = new Human; Mammal mammal = new Mammal();` - ведь в итоге всё равно создается два экземпляра класса - производный и на основе его базовый?

P.S.: Я думаю, что мой вопрос не дублирует [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240588/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-upcast-%D0%B2-c). Мой вопрос о технической стороне - почему апкаст был, а функционал остался как у производного класса.

Comment: Так ведь `human` остаётся со своим значением, а вот новый экземпляр базового класса `mammal` создаётся из `human` без использования конструктора, только привидением.

Comment: Самое простое - таким образом вы можете например засунуть кучу разных животных в 1 список. То есть в `List<Mammal>` влезет объект любого типа, наследующего класс `Mammal`. Пример нужен, или так понятно?

Comment: Касты никоим образом не меняют тип объекта, поля и методы никуда не могут таинственным методом исчезнуть из памяти, можете убедиться вызвав `GetType()`. Меняется лишь интерфейс для взаимодействия с реальным объектом, а за допустимостью этого следит компилятор.

Comment: В первом случае у вас создаться только один объект, на который будут указывать 2 ссылки типов `Human` и `Mammal`. Во втором случае вы создаете 2 объекта двух разных типов.

Comment: Апкаст не изменяет объект, не создает экземпляр, он просто меняет тип контейнера объекта. Вот у вас есть `Mammal mammal = (Mammal)human;`, а теперь попробуйте `Console.WriteLine(mammal.GetType().Name);`, и вы увидите, что реальный тип экземпляра не поменялся. После апкаста возможен даункаст с к тому типу, с которого был апкаст, например `Human h = (Human)mammal`, но даункаст возможен только если объект соответствует типу, к которому вы его даункастите. То есть объект `Mammal m = new Mammal()` выдаст ошибку `InvalidCastException` при попытке даункаста `Human h = (Human)m`.

Comment: _Но после этого фрагмента кода у экземпляра human сохраняются методы и переменные производного класса_ - как ты это проверил? В дубликате явно приведен пример, когда это не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Приведение типов никак не меняет содержимое объектов, т.е. при приведении не создаётся новых экземпляров классов.
2. Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433314/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-upcast-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0) весьма подробно расписано в каких случаях необходимо использовать upcast. Но, пожалуй, в 95% случаев осуществлять явный upcast не имеет смысла. Компилятор C# весьма умный в этом отношении и приведение типов осуществляет неявным образом максимально комфортно для разработчиков.

Нижеприведенный пример демонстрирует базовые возможности объекта, приведенного к родительскому классу.

Обратите внимание на строчку `mammal.AnyHumanMethod();` Она вызывает ошибку компиляции. C# является строго типизированным языком. Компилятор следит, чтобы обращения ко всем членам класса производилось именно у того типа, к которому приведен объект.

```
class Program
{
    class Mammal
    {
        public virtual string Name => "It is a mammal";
    }

    class Human : Mammal
    {
        public override string Name => "It is a human";

        public void AnyHumanMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method was called");
        }
    }
        
    static void Main()
    {
        var human = new Human();
        Console.WriteLine(human.Name); // Будет выведено "It is a human"
        human.AnyHumanMethod(); // Этот вызов корректен и допустим

        var mammal = (Mammal)human;
            
        // Сейчас всё равно будет вызван метод Human, т.к. несмотря на
        // приведение, в переменной mammal хранится экземпляр класса Human
        Console.WriteLine(mammal.Name); // Будет выведено "It is a human"
            
        // У класса Mammal нет метода AnyHumanMethod, он есть только в классе Human
        mammal.AnyHumanMethod(); // Ошибка компляции!

        // Никакого создания нового объекта не происходит при приведение типов.
        // Экземпляры классов human и mammal равны.
        Console.WriteLine($"Сейчас будет возвращено значение True: {human == mammal}");
    }
}
```