# Наследование в C# (Массивы обьектов)

Tags: c#

Я немного упростил свой код чтоб мне могли обьяснить.
Короче есть базовый клас Vegetable, и также Tomato, который наследуют базовый. Я создаю список типа Vegetable и добавляю туда обьекты типа Tomato, указывая в каждом количество помидорок (переменная quantity).
Проблема заключаеться в конце, когда я пытаюсь вывести весь список обьектов с их соответствующим количеством.
При дебаге увидел, что обьекты имеют 2 переменные:

quantity (Vegetable) [int]: 0 *//это то, что выводит в конце*

quantity [int]: 2 *//тут как раз число, котороя я вводил*

Обьясните, пожалуйста, почему в обьектах двое переменных, и как мне в конце вывести правильную переменную.

```
class Vegetable
{
   public int quantity;
}
class Tomato : Vegetable
{
   new public int quantity { get; set; }
}

class Program13
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
  List<Vegetable> vegetableList = new List<Vegetable>();

  Tomato tomato1 = new Tomato();
  Console.WriteLine("Write quantity of tomatoes1");
  vegetableList.Add(tomato1);
  tomato1.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

  Tomato tomato2 = new Tomato();
  Console.WriteLine("Write quantity of tomatoes2");
  vegetableList.Add(tomato2);
  tomato2.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

  Console.WriteLine("Salad contains:");
  foreach (var obj in vegetableList)
  {
     Console.WriteLine($"{obj.quantity} {obj.GetType()}");
  }
```

}
}

Выводит это:
Salad contains:

0 Tomato
0 Tomato

Comment: Понял что дело при создании обьектов. Типо надо 
*Vegetable tomato1 = new Tomato()*
а я создавал
*Tomato tomato1 = new Tomato()*
Но я не вижу разницы. Основы ООП изучал в c++, поэтому с новыми реалиями c# еще сложно. Обьясните пожалуйста почему так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вы используете "сокрытие", то есть ваше свойство `new public int quantity { get; set; }` как бы скрывает поле `public int quantity;` (см про оператор new). При сокрытии по сути оба quantity остаются, какой из них будет вызван зависит от типа переменной.

То есть вот тут `myObject.quantity` - если переменная `myObject` имеет тип `Vegetable` - то будет из него использоваться поле, если же `myObject` имеет тип `Tomato` - то оттуда.

Вообще это редко когда имеет смысл так делать. Обычно, если надо переопределить что то в производном классе, то в базовом это чтото (свойство или метод, например) объявляют виртуальными (virtual) и в производных классах уже перегружают (override). В этом случае тип переменной не важен, всегда будет вызываться код производного класса.

Пример

```
class Vegetable
{
    public virtual int quantity { get; set; }
}
class Tomato : Vegetable
{
    public override int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Проверка

```
List<Vegetable> vegetableList = new List<Vegetable>();

Tomato tomato1 = new Tomato();
tomato1.quantity = 10;  
vegetableList.Add(tomato1);

Console.WriteLine("Salad contains:");
foreach (var obj in vegetableList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{obj.quantity} {obj.GetType().Name}");
}
```

Вывод

```
Salad contains:
10 Tomato
```

Конечно, пример искусственный, так как на практике нет смысла перегружать что то, если в перегрузке логика никак не отличается, но суть ясна я думаю.

Comment: Спасибо! С переопределением разобрался, но все еще не понимаю смысл строки 
*Vegetable tomato1 = new Tomato()*
Я впринципе не понимаю эту строку. Увидел как другие обьявляют переменные при наследовании и решил попробовать - сработало, но почему не понимаю.

Comment: Это называется upcast, подробнее читайте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433315/179763)