# C# Коллекции и наследование

Tags: c#

У меня есть два класса. Один базовый, другой производный.
Я создаю список, указываю что состоит из элементов базового класса.
Без проблем могу добавить туда экземпляр производного класса.
Но при обращении к элементу списка, я не могу обратится к публичным полям производного класса.
Как это исправить?
Хотя перегруженный метод ToString() работает нормально и выводит поля производного класса.
Значит они все таки хранятся там.

```
List<TourPackage> lst = new List<TourPackage>();
        lst.Add(new SpecialTourPackage("Песчаный тур", 32, 50000, 40, 25, 30));
        lst[0].ShowInfo();
```

Comment: не надо в заголовке писать `См. описание`, кому нужно - тот сам догадается.

Comment: [Зачем нужен upcast (повышающее приведение типа)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433314/179763), [Причины использования DownCast](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432183/179763)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int discount = ((SpecialTourPackage)lst[0]).Discount;
```

Answer (score 1):

Через ссылку базового класса вы можете обращаться только к полям и методам классов-наследников, которые определены в базовом классе.

Конкретно в вашем примере вы можете явно преобразовать значение в производный класс и использовать его как вам угодно.

```cs
SpecialTourPackage pack = (SpecialTourPackage)lst[0];
pack.ShowSpecialInfo();
//Или
((SpecialTourPackage)lst[0]).ShowSpecialInfo();
```

Больше объяснений можно найти здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1271081/302769